# Dynamic Character Counter - Label Not Showing Anything

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to make a dynamic character counter that displays the text.length from a textbox. I am trying to use textchanged, but I think I am missing a piece because my label does not display a value at all.

ASP

```
<tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle">
        Note to Buyer:
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNoteToBuyer" runat="server" Height="150px" MaxLength="425" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="400px"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>    
        <asp:Label ID="lblCharacterCount" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

VB

```
Protected Sub txtNoteToBuyer_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtNoteToBuyer.TextChanged
    lblCharacterCount.Text = Len(txtNoteToBuyer.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't do this server-side. Use JavaScript instead. Otherwise you'll have to post-back the page on every single character entered.

Comment: Good call. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Odds are your event isn't firing. You need to set the AutoPostBack property of your text box to true.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNoteToBuyer" runat="server" Height="150px" MaxLength="425" TextMode="MultiLine"
                        Width="400px" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

However, this will probably result in slow response. I would recommend using JavaScript to dynamically update the count on the front end instead of requiring a postback.

To do that, you would need to add `OnKeyUp="updateCount();"` to your text box and add a script to update the count to your page. Here is one example of a script that would work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateCount() {
        var countLabel = document.getElementById("<%=lblCharacterCount.ClientId%>");
        var textCount = document.getElementById("<%=txtNoteToBuyer.ClientId%>").value.length;
        countLabel.textContent = textCount + "";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I appreciate your reply! I tried both of these methods, but my label still appears blank when I run it.

For the javascript portion, am I putting the script in the aspx page where my textboxes and labels are?

Comment: You can add the script to a separate file and load that on your page, but for simplicity's sake, yes it needs to be on the aspx page where your textboxes and labels are. The easiest way to be sure it works is to put it in your <head> tag.

Comment: I have it with all of my other scripts at the top, but my label still appears blank. The fact that it doesn't work with the AutoPostBack too makes me think I am still missing a piece somewhere.

Comment: Make sure that when you are using the script, you don't have AutoPostBack set to true. That will circumvent the script.

Comment: Oh, I just realized I had quotation marks wrong on the var countLabel line. I have edited my answer to put them in the correct position. That might be why the script is not working.

Comment: I actually noticed the quotes and made the corrections in my script.

I missed the part about not having AutoPostBack and the script. I removed AutoPostBack and it is now working! You rock!